# javascript_include_tag causes ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am getting this error in a staging environment.  So far I cannot reproduce this error on my local machine in development.  This is the error that I am getting:

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in widgets#options:


app/views/wa_admin/widgets/options.html.erb:50:in `_app_views_wa_admin_widgets_options_html_erb___4438918489025291975_70301100178220'
```

The line of code that is causing this is this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "scriptaculous-js-1.9.0/lib/prototype" %>
```

Which that file does exist within the assets/javascripts directory.  Does anybody know what the issue is?  Or at least how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected that you can't re-produce the error in development; because in development the fallback to `app/assets` directory is enabled (
`config.assets.compile = true`) .. check `config/environments/development.rb`.

But in staging, production environments: the fallback to `app/assets` directory option is disabled.

Thus, the solution is to precompile assets during the deployment.

To make sure that this is the reason, You can run locally `rake assets:precompile` then push the newly created `assets` directory, then deploy to staging, it should work.

Comment: then push the newly created assets directory, which assets directory you are talking about?